# How to set the frame rate of iOS camera

Tags: ios, camera

I'm new to iOS coding, and now I want to set the frame of iOS front camera, like 18 fps or 25 fps. Here is my codes, I'm confused that no matter how I change the value of activeVideoMinFrameDuration and activeVideoMaxFrameDuration, the final video is always 30fps.

```
 do {
            try videoDevice!.lockForConfiguration()
            videoDevice!.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 20)
            videoDevice!.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 20)
            videoDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch let error as NSError {
                NSLog("Could not lock device for configuration: %@", error)
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to set

```
videoFileOutput.movieFragmentInterval = CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 25)
```